# how can I run an exisiting project in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, launch

I am new in react, and now I have an available project which is needed some kind of development. The whole project consists of app and build folder and both of them also have index.html file and some other staff. How can I launch this project for viewing its demo in linux?could anyone explain the process step by step?

thanks in advance

Comment: The question cannot be answered. This totally depends on the project. package.json scripts section should be examined to understand how the project is built. It's conventional that `npm i && npm start` results in running a project but it's unnecessary that this is true for any project.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:** Via Node

1. Install Node [Install Node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/) on linux machine
2. Once successfully installed, go to project folder and run `npm install` to install dependencies.
3. Run command `"npm start"` or in background `"nohup npm start &"` will start default application on 3000 port, from browser check `http://IP/domain name:3000`

**Approach 2** Via Yarn

1. Install Yarn on linux machine [Install Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/)
2. from project folder run `yarn install` will install all dependencies.
3. run `yarn build` will create complied code in `/build` folder
4. Install `apache` or `Ngnix` and move build folder content to `apache` or `ngnix` web root folder
5. Access app from `http://IP` or domain name if seted up for ip.